# Homework: What to submit as part of a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, svn, installation

I have a very simple Ruby on Rails project that has an ActiveRecords model with some validations, and a pretty basic view and controller that allows basic add/update/delete/search interaction with database.

I'd like for the professor to be able to use the website, assuming he has Rails3 installed.

What would be a good way to submit this project?  Specifically: what files and folders should I include, and what files should I exclude?  What about directions for the professor?  Anything else that I should include?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that a good idea will be to develop your project locally and then uploaded to a [github](http://github.com) repository for the professor to see your code. If you want a free, easy and EXCELLENT place to host your application try [heroku](http://heroku.com), it is a cloud application platform where you can host your project(if you use a shared database < 5MB you will be able to do it with the free plan). I recommend you to include a README file a the root of your app where you add all your directions.